Dell OS10.5.x - DOT1Q encapsulation possible on routed port
Wanting to connect Cisco and Dell (S4128F-ON) switches using routed ports and dot1q encapsulation.
On the cisco side I use the following config:
interface ethernet 1/8
    encapsulation dot1q 123
    ip address 10.1.200.1/30
    ip ospf authentication message-digest
    ip ospf message-digest key 1 md5 1 xxxxxxxxxxxx
    ip opsf network point-to-point
    no ip ospf passive-interface
    ip router ospf 1 area 0.0.0.0
    no shutdown

On the Dell side we have the following config so far.
interface ethernet1/1/6
 no shutdown
 no switchport
 ip address 10.1.200.1/30
 flowcontrol receive on
 ip ospf 100 area 0.0.0.0
 ip ospf message-digest-key 1 md5 xxxxxxx
 ip ospf network point-to-point

Is it possible to do dot1q encapsulation on the Dell switch? Or do I need to create a trunk with an SVI?

You can't use the same IP address on 2 ends of the same link.

On the Dell switch, you need to select switchport mode and permit the required VLANs:
interface ethernet1/1/6
 no shutdown
 switchport mode trunk
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 123

The IP address needs to be bound to the VLAN (SVI). I don't think a routed port with VLAN subinterfaces is possible.
